# How to make subprocess to press a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm making a script and my app.py looks like this;

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt-get", "update"])
subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt-get", "upgrade"])
```

And you might already know that this apt-gets are asking for a confirmation. I know I can put an extra `-y` at the end but I need to know how to make it so it presses enter when prompted.

There are several prompts that doesn't accept `-y` so that's why I'm asking.

For example;
[adding a repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWAR0.png) or [this screen when you run apt-get upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzbXy.png)

So I need to press `Enter` automatically for these prompts. Which should be something like in this concept;

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt-get", "update"])
(PRESS ENTER HERE WHEN PROMPTED)
subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt-get", "upgrade"])
(PRESS ENTER HERE WHEN PROMPTED WHICH ASKS YOU ABOUT 3 TIMES)
```

Comment: Have you tried `--force-yes` ?

Comment: how do I do that exactly?

Comment: If they are reading from `stdin`, the simplest way is to put each "enter" as a newline in a text file, along with any other replies, and redirect stdin from the file.  For example: `subprocess.call("sudo apt-get update < cmd.txt", shell = True)`

Comment: Actually the code I pasted is exactly what my app.py is. So I'm not using anything else like stdin or something like that since I don't know how to use them.

Comment: I meant if `apt-get` is reading from `stdin`

Comment: Why do you even use pyton if you are just using it to run subprocess? You can do that more easily in a shell script.

Comment: I thought python would be a better fit. Obviously I can do it with a shell script tho.

Comment: @zvone besides, is it possible to do what I'm asking with shell script? I mean is it easier to make shell script to press enter when prompted?

Comment: @aradabir007 please check my answer; I think it may be of use for you.

Comment: @zvone it looks like so; however the OP has asked for a Python implementation and I don't think arguing their question is going to do much to it. I encourage you to post an answer if you think you can do it more easily